# Remove a property by name in OpenMesh

Tags: c++, graphics, openmesh

In OpenMesh, once a named property is added to an element, it will be permanent in the sense that the property survives the scope of the property manager as explained [here](https://www.graphics.rwth-aachen.de/media/openmesh_static/Documentations/OpenMesh-Doc-Latest/a04338.html). My question is, how to remove such a property by its name?

So far I tried removing by the property manager and even this one fails:

```
auto face_props = OpenMesh::FProp<FaceProp>(mesh, "face_props");
mesh.remove_property(face_props);
```

with the error

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘OpenMesh::TriMesh_ArrayKernelT<>::remove_property(OpenMesh::PropertyManager<OpenMesh::FPropHandleT<FaceProp>, int>&)’
```

Is there a `remove_property` function where I could write `remove_property("face_props")` (or similar) to remove the property?

**Edit:** The following gives the same error:

```
mesh.remove_property( OpenMesh::getProperty<OpenMesh::FaceHandle, FaceProp>(mesh, "face_props") );
```

I suspect that `mesh.remove_property()` expects a property handle object, but `getProperty()` returns a property manager. I don't see how to get around this.

**Edit2:** I guess an alternative question would be: how to get a property handle to a property from a property manager?

**Edit3**: Looking at the [source](https://www.graphics.rwth-aachen.de/media/openmesh_static/Documentations/OpenMesh-Doc-Latest/a00482_source.html), it seems like `PropertyManager` has a member function `deleteProperty()` but a) is private and b) it only deletes the property if `retain` is not set which I assume would be set for named properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently one can define a lower level property handle and then use `get_property_handle` which takes a handle as reference and updates it in place. This works:

```
    OpenMesh::FPropHandleT< FaceProp > fprop;
    mesh.get_property_handle(fprop, "face_props");
    mesh.remove_property( fprop );
```

I wish this was better documented. Or that I was better in C++.